# One Drive REST API - Current authenticated context is not valid for this request

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to build a background service that authenticates with One Drive via REST Calls. For now, I've registered a test application in the portal from my own email id and able to get a token. 
But when I try to see all files from my drive using this end point - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children, I receive a BAD request - Current authenticated context is not valid for this request response. 
I wouldn't need any administrative consent because there will be only user from this background service at all times. The article I referred is here - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service#3-get-administrator-consent

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are making a request using application permissions (client_credentials flow) - where there is no signed-in user context. Your request is to /me, and /me is basically an alias for the signed-in user . You should use  `GET /users/{idOrUserPrincipalName}/drive` instead .

To use application permissions or delegate permissions are based on your requirement . You may refer to [authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios) for more details . Or you should explain more about your current scenario .

Comment: thanks. I ditched one-drive and have moved to dropbox due its single access token be used for any number of times.